# Why does Scala choose the type 'Product' for 'for' expressions involving Either and value definitions

Tags: scala, type-inference, for-comprehension

If I create a for comprehension with a value definition with Option, it works as expected:

```
scala> for (a <- Some(4); b <- Some(5); val p = a * b) yield p
res0: Option[Int] = Some(20)
```

Doing the same thing with Either works if i have no value definition:

```
scala> for (a <- Right(4).right; b <- Right(5).right) yield a * b
res1: Either[Nothing,Int] = Right(20)
```

But if i used the value definition, scala seems to infer the wrong container type for the for comprehension:

```
scala> for (a <- Right(4).right; b <- Right(5).right; val p = a * b) yield p
<console>:8: error: value map is not a member of Product with Serializable with Either[Nothing,(Int, Int)]
for (a <- Right(4).right; b <- Right(5).right; val p = a * b) yield p
                            ^
```

Why does it do this? What ways around this behavior are available?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The problems comes from `val p = a*b`
If you write the simpler

for (a <- Right(4).right; b <- Right(5).right) yield a*b

it compiles and you get the proper result.

Your problem has two causes

First, the `Either` projections `map` and `flatMap` do not have the usual signature , namely for routines map and flatMap defined in a generic class `M[A]`, `(A => B) => M[B]` and `(A => M[B]) => M[B]`. The `M[A]` the routine are defined in is `Either[A,B].RightProjection`, but in results and argument, we have `Either[A,B]` and not the projection.

Second, the way `val p = a*b` in the for comprehension is translated. Scala Reference, 6.19 p 90:

> A generator p <- e followed by a value definition p′ = e′ is
>   translated to the following generator of pairs of values, where x and
>   x′ are fresh names:

```
(p,p′) <- for(x@p<-e) yield {val x′@p′ = e′; (x,x′)}
```

Let's simplify the code just a little bit, dropping the `a <-`. Also, `b` and `p` renamed to `p` and `pp` to be closer to the rewrite rule, with `pp` for `p'`. `a` supposed to be in scope
for(p <- Right(5).right; val pp = a*p) yield pp

following the rule, we have to replace the generator + definition. What is around that, `for(` and `)yield pp`, unchanged.

```
for((p, pp) <- for(x@p <- Right(5).right) yield{val xx@pp = a*p; (x,xx)}) yield pp
```

The inner for is rewritten to a simple map

```
for((p, pp) <- Right(5).right.map{case x@p => val xx@pp = a*p; (x,xx)}) yield pp
```

Here is the problem. The `Right(5).right.map(...)` is of type `Either[Nothing, (Int,Int)]`, not `Either.RightProjection[Nothing, (Int,Int)]` as we would want. It does not work in the outer for (which converts to a `map` too. There is no `map` method on `Either`, it is defined on projections only.

If you look closely at your error message, it says so, even if it mentions `Product` and `Serializable`, it says that it is an `Either[Nothing, (Int, Int)]`, and that no map is defined on it. The pair `(Int, Int)` comes directly from the rewrite rule.

The for comprehension is intended to work well when respecting the proper signature. With the trick with `Either` projections (which has its advantages too), we get this problem.

Comment: Ah, that's starting to make sense. You have a few typos that tripped me up at first (missing primes, subtle type errors, etc) that i'll clean up shortly.

Comment: The interesting result of the above is that if i have consistent monadic types i will be fine. So if i only care about right projections i could create an implicit like the following which indeed fixes the problem: implicit def RightProjection[A,B](v: Either[A,B]): Either.RightProjection[A,B] = v.right

Comment: Again, huge thanks for the thorough writeup! I'd read the reference and still hadn't figured out what was going on. Obviously in this simple example, a*b can be moved to the yield, but if that is replaced by a complex calculation that needs to be passed to a function that returns another Either (repeat this several times), being able to use an intermediate value assignment can be much cleaner looking then having to have multiple levels of chained for/yield statements.

Comment: I guess the other option i have is to do the boxing myself, which is close to what the compiler was doing with Option anyway: for (a <- Right(4).right; b <- Right(5).right; p <- Right(a * b).right) yield p

Comment: Sorry for the numerous typos and thanks for cleaning up. For making me aware of the problem too. I think implicit conversion to right conversion is quite convenient, one still can use .left if needed.